# Windows Server 2019 won't boot anymore after a restart

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 on a cloud provider, using VMWare as Hypervisor.
Yesterday I've rebooted after it was begun to be slower. It hasn't restarted anymore.

From the console of vmware I see the initial loading with the windows logo in the first 2~6 seconds, then black screen with the spinning icon, and it stays like this forever.

Sending CTRL-ALT-DEL does nothing.
Remote Desktop and all other services (FTP, HTTP) doesn't work at all.
I can ping the machine, so network is working.

Tried restarting several times but nothing change.

what can I do to restore this machine?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Windows updates. Do you have any snapshots available in ESXi? If not, you can try to rollback the changes inside the Windows using additional options during startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows update killed it probably, like it happens to W10.

To fix it the best way is to restore from a snapshot, if you have any.

If you do not have any snapshot, perhaps a restore point within it. For that, power it on/off 3 times so you get the safe mode start-up menu. Note that the restore modes of the 10-based Windows versions are entirely unreliable, so I'd go with snapshot restore if possible.

Also, you can try to enable low-res video or start in safe mode and restart then in normal mode using the same menu.

If none of the above work, hopefully you have it backed up somewhere.

Comment: Finally you helped me to go in the right direction. Restored to a previous state running in safe mode (F8), I've discovered that the issue was caused by Ransomware ACCDFISA 2. Maybe due to a poor admin password, otherwise, I can't understand how it has been installed

Comment: Make sure all traces of it are removed and reset passwords for all accounts of that machine; also use more complex passwords. Read this as it applies to passwords too: https://xaeus.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/security-questions-for-password-recovery-how-to-make-them-actually-useful-en/